# Overflow attribute on <td> does not create a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I trying to create a table cell `<td>` with an overflow but it doesn't work...

There's my CSS code:

```css
td.blog_content
{
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 360px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```php
<td class="blog_content"><?php echo $blog['content']; ?></td>
```

It would create a simple box with a scrollbar if the text is too long...

Comment: And of course we wouldn't use a `<table>` for styling so `.blog_content` is obviously tabular data ;)

Comment: What a title... "CSS styling doesn't work". Good, we can just fire all our designers then, they've been doing it wrong all these years.

Comment: @Ktash It's only the part where I have a bug...

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux A bug? That's what we're here for ;) Modern CSS can handle most any situation a table can.

Comment: @Ktash Indeed, but CSS2.1 can't handle anything! CSS3 cans but I'm not using it for compatibility reason...

Comment: @Borealid LOL! I hate question in title. So I just describe it ;)

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Like I said, _modern_ CSS can handle most anything. This means we can make IE7+ (which is CSS2 +some) support most anything a table can do. If you're talking CSS3, than there is nothing a table can do that CSS can't. If you'd like to get it fixed, I'd recommend posting it as a question as many here in the community (myself included at times) are good at solving those issues.

Comment: @Ktash: "Modern CSS can handle most any situation a table can" - Really! Horziontal as well as Verticaly alignment using ONLY CSS properties that are ONLY meant to do that?

Comment: @Jawad Yes. Depends on the content which you want to align, but yes. This is turning into a full discussion and debate that is off-topic though. If you really want to get into a discussion about it, I'd be more than happy to oblige, but why don't we move it to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3840/css).

Comment: @Ktash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159026/how-to-make-the-content-100-height-and-equal-height-columns-in-this-layout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a `<div>`. I'm pretty sure the overflow attribute is not defined for a `<td>` element, at least in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TD) it's not.

```
<td class="blog_content">
    <div><?php echo $blog['content']; ?></div>
</td>

.blog_content div {
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to wrap it in a <div> in HTML5 too

Answer (score 2):

Set `table-layout: fixed;` on the `table` containing your cells. Alternatively, wrap the contents of each cell in a `div` and apply the styles to that.

Comment: Are you sure the `table-layout` property affects this? [I can't seem to get it to work.](http://jsfiddle.net/ySUVg/5/)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have to wrap the contents into a div:

```
<td class="blog_content"><div><?php echo $blog['content']; ?></div></td>

td.blog_content div
{
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 360px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/1747301

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can force scrollbar by `overflow: auto` in a table-cell, but you sure can with a `div`-tag.
Have you considered using a `div`?

Answer (score 1):

You can put :

```
<td class="blog_content">
  <div style="overflow:auto;width:200px;">
      <?php echo $blog['content']; ?>
  </div>
</td>
```

Adding a DIV element will with fixed height or width and overflow property to auto will make it scroll.