# Overflow: auto does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, overflow

I have a table. Its `<td>` have `overflow: auto`.

The width is set to be 100px. In **Firefox only**, text that exceeds 100px is **not** hidden and replaced with a scrollbar.

How can I hide content and have a scrollbar when it exceeds the width of its  container?

http://jsfiddle.net/be6tM/10/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152042/overflow-attribute-on-td-does-not-create-a-scrollbar) maybe solve your problem

[nickb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862594/nickb) answer: *"Try wrapping it in a `<div>`. I'm pretty sure the overflow attribute is not defined for a `<td>` element, at least in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TD) it's not."*

try to put your `overflow:auto` to the `wrapper` hope this can help you

```
pre, div {
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/be6tM/13/)

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do this would be to add this to the **Html**

```
<td class="first">
    <div>Don ovonMrLongNameIsMe!!!</div>
</td>
```

and this to the **CSS**

```
div {
    overflow:auto;    
}

td {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
    div {
        overflow:auto;    
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        min-width: 100px;
        max-width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<table>    
  <tr>
    <td class="first">
        <div>Don ovonMrLongNameIsMe!!!</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```