# overflow scroll not working in table when using firefox

Tags: html, css

I try to show a scrollbar in my table if the value of the cell is too long, i tried it with `overflow` but as you can see it does not work, there is no scrollbar, the word is displayed in it's full length

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
    overflow: scroll;
    color: red;
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th class="test">Filename</th>
  <th>value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">Very long filename for demonstration</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**:

I just noticed that the scrollbars are showing if i am using Chrome Browser, but not if i use Firefox. So unfortunatelly `overflow` does not seem to be compatible with firefox.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td

Comment: @LucaGiardina, oh mee too if i am using chrome, i just noticed that it does not work if use firefox

Comment: You can use a div within a td. I believe overflow works for div in firefox as shown in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328233/overflow-auto-does-not-work-in-firefox

Comment: Could you try using `-moz-scrollbars-horizontal`inside your `.test`rule? Should be the mozilla specific 'overflow' option.

Comment: Nothing happens if i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare

```
.test {
display:inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

then the `overflow:scroll` will work in Firefox as well:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th class="test">Filename</th>
  <th>value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">Very long filename for demonstration</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

**Version 2:**

Main changes:

- `td` has `display: block;` instead of `display: inline-block;`
- `td` has `overflow:auto;` instead of `overflow:scroll;`

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  max-width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>account_requests</td></tr>
<tr><td>backend.template</td></tr>
<tr><td>firmware.host</td></tr>
<tr><td>frontend.template</td></tr>
<tr><td>license.host</td></tr>
<tr><td>licensing.host</td></tr>
<tr><td>mail.auto_smtp_authentification_password</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this does not work properly as you can see in my screenshot. The scroll bar is showing even though the text is not oversized and the table looks weird.
http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=98793

Comment: The setup in the image you link to above and the setup you posted in your original question seem quite different. I have added a *Version 2* to the answer above.

Comment: Thank you, but this did not really improved it for me, now it looks like this: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=98802

Comment: Yes. I thought that's exactly what you are aiming for: _I try to show a scrollbar in my table if the value of the cell is too long_

Comment: You are right sorry. But i mean it still looks weird, there are now white gaps between the rows for some unknown reason.

Comment: Come on, be fair. You asked a specific question with a specific setup. I showed you a viable solution to achieve what you wanted with that setup. You then indicated that didn't work with a different setup. I then showed you a viable solution to achieve what you wanted with that different setup. Now you are asking about something completely different. Please accept the answer and ask another question. I'm happy to help you, but questions must be discrete and self-contained. Thanks.

Comment: It was not different, the table in my screenshot only had a few more rows.. It does not work exactly as it works in google chrome,, just look at the screenshot how messed the table looks, would you accpet this as a solution?

Comment: Please run the **Version 2** code snippet in the post above again and let me know if what you see is or is not the desired behaviour you asked about in your original question. It is (to my understanding) and frankly, I'm pretty pleased with it. If it's not what you're looking for I'm happy to leave it for future searchers and move on to other questions. If it is what you were originally looking for please accept the answer - and if you still have other things to fix, please ask another question.