# overflow: auto; works fine in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have been searching the web for a solution for 3 hours without success. I want to set overflow: auto to  tag as follows:

```
td {
 overflow:auto!important;  
}
```

It works fine in chrome but not in Firefox. I checked my entire css file by w3c css validator.
There is no error too. Any idea please? I am sorry if it is very silly question but everyone have to learn this first to be expert.

Comment: please code or jsfiddle.net

Comment: Did u try to explore element on FF?

Comment: Yes. I explored element  by firebug

Comment: @sattar_kuet.bd Please accept the answer if it has answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a `<div>`. The overflow attribute is not defined for a `<td>` element.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9152070/3222041)

Try to put your `overflow:auto` to the wrapper like this,

```
pre, div {
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

**[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axDj8/)**

Comment: Hello five year old answer! This worked for me in 2019, just wondering if I have missed something or if this is still a relevant solution? Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  td {
      height: 20px; // mention a height
      overflow:auto!important;  
  }
```

Comment: send me ur design structure or css

Comment: There are a lot of code(about 1000 line). All code is not my concern. only <td> tag  and its css in my code are my concern. Here is html of <td>: 
<td>
<div id="edit-checkboxes-20-wrapper" class="form-item form-option">
<label class="option" for="edit-checkboxes-20">
</div>
</td>  
and the css is : 
td {
 height: 20px !important;
 overflow:auto!important;
}

Comment: Instead of add the **overflow:auto** in td, add this one in class of a div. It'll be helpful.